# Adjust the size of panels plotted through ggplot() and facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have a dataframe to plot multiple panels with the same x axis and different y axis. The number of columns may vary. I use ggplot and facet_grid to plot these panels.

The problems is that the size of the overall plot seems to be the same, thus when more panels appear, the size of each one is very small.

Are there any ways to fix the size of each panel and the overall size of the figure vary depending on the number of columns and panels? Thanks.

Comment: If you're talking in an R terminal, in RStudio, or similar, the answer is: it never matters, because R is not controlling the size of the underlying canvas window, so you're unable to control that aspect. If you're using rmarkdown or sweave and rendering to a PDF, then *you* control the canvas size with `knitr` chunks. If you're talking on a web page, it might matter (you can control it), though you need to guard against resizes and fluid architectures. Regardless, though, the question is lacking context to be able to help much.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using Shiny to develop a UI and would like to display such a figure with multiple panels there. So the size is important to me. I am new to this issue, so not sure if I still miss some context here. Could you give me any clue on this concern?

Comment: Perhaps the fact that it's shiny doesn't really solve all questions I have, but having a reprex that demonstrates your issue would be useful. You can control some theme aesthetics with "human sizes", e.g., `theme(plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 2, "cm"))`, perhaps other areas can use the same technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry for unintended self promotion, but I wrote a function a while back to more precisely control the sizes of panels. I've put it in a package on <s>github</s> CRAN. I'm not sure how it'd work with a shiny app, but here is how you'd work with it in ggplot2.

You can control the relative sizes of the width/height by setting plain numbers for the rows/colums.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

df <- expand.grid(1:12, 3:5)
df$x <- 1

ggplot(df, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(Var1 ~ Var2) +
  force_panelsizes(rows = 1, cols = 2, TRUE)
```

[image]

You can also control the absolute sizes of the panel by setting an `unit` object. Note that you can set them for individual rows and columns too if you know the number of panels in advance.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(Var1 ~ Var2) +
  force_panelsizes(rows = unit(runif(12) + 0.1, "cm"), 
                   cols = unit(c(1, 5, 2), "cm"), 
                   TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hope that helped.

Comment: The self promotion is absolutely justified- although I admit I keep wondering about the name of your package...